# Does Anakin “bring balance to the force” by fathering Luke and Leia?

Tags: luke-skywalker, anakin-skywalker, princess-leia, star-wars

Watching the Star Wars series again with my younglings and I feel like Ani and Padme brought balance to the force by making Luke and Leia… it feels like he didn’t fulfill the prophecy, but as even wise Yoda explained, interpreting the future and prophecies is very difficult. Is there a more clear explanation of “bringing balance to the force” than my genius (/s) interpretation?

Comment: It's clear from the dupe answers that George Lucas considered the ending of the Sith to be the way in which Anakin brought balance to the Force - "***... [to] fulfill the prophecy where he brings balance to the Force by doing away with the Sith and getting rid of evil in the universe***"

Comment: I always thought that Yoda misunderstood the prophecy. Before *Revenge of the Sith", there were two Sith ("Always two there are", in Yoda's own words), and after, there were also only two Jedi; Yoda and Obi-Wan. If that isn't "bringing balance", what is?  :-)